# SQL, insert statement with partial select and predefined data

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

I do have table 'user' where is some columns including id (row id) and email. I need to insert row to another table with some data but I do have found somehow id from user table using email value, how I am doing that?

table X  (table to insert new row)
  user_id, column1, column2

table user 
id, email, other columns

Comment: [`INSERT .. SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) using a derived table.

Comment: You can “select” static values in a `SELECT` statement as well …

Comment: It was more easy than I thought ...

This will do the job:

INSERT INTO table_x (user_id, column1, column2) 
 VALUES ((select id from user where email='example@hmail.com'), 'data', data2); Thanks to everyone !

Comment: This is a useful question but it isn't clear what databases or versions this is applicable for e.g for all SQL's or only Mysql and for what versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE x_table (user_id VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(30), column1 VARCHAR(30), column2 VARCHAR(30));
CREATE TABLE user_table (user_id VARCHAR(30), email VARCHAR(30));

<-- example values -->
INSERT INTO user_table (user_id, email) (
    SELECT '10', 'x1@mail.com' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '20', 'x2@mail.com' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '30', 'x3@mail.com' FROM dual
 );

<-- Solution -->
INSERT INTO x_table (user_id, email,column1, column2) (
    SELECT (SELECT user_id FROM user_table WHERE email='x1@mail.com'),'x1@mail.com', 'value_column1_1','value_column2_1' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT (SELECT user_id FROM user_table WHERE email='x2@mail.com'),'x2@mail.com', 'value_column1_2','value_column2_2' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT (SELECT user_id FROM user_table WHERE email='x3@mail.com'),'x3@mail.com', 'value_column1_3','value_column2_3' FROM dual
);
```

Comment: explaine your code